# Get element by name in express/node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm creating an express/node app and I want to get an element by name but the server crashes when I use `document.getElementsByName()` so how can I get an element by name on express/node?

Comment: Node runs on the server, document elements are on the client.

Answer (score 1):

The `document` object that has `document.getElementsByName()` is something that Javascript that runs in a browser can use.  Javascript that runs in nodejs cannot use that as the document lives in the browser, not in nodejs.

It appears that you may not quite understand the client/server nature of the web.  A user starts up a browser that runs on their computer.  When you type an URL into the URL bar in the browser and hit enter, it sends a request to a web server (a different computer usually off somewhere else on the internet).  That web server receives the request, looks at what the path of the URL is and any parameters on the URL and then sends back content.

If what the URL represented was an HTML page, then the browser (running on the end-user's computer) takes that HTML page, parses it and displays it in the browser.  If there are any references to other resources such as images or scripts, then the browser also requests those from the server.

If there is Javascript in the web page, then the browser runs that Javascript in the browser.  It is this Javascript where `document.getElementsByName()` can be used.  This is not nodejs Javascript, this is Javascript meant to run in the web page.

Where people occasionally get confused is that webpage Javascript actually lives on the server's hard drive somewhere.  When the browser requests that script or that webpage, the nodejs server gets that request and sends the webpage or the script back to the browser.  So, while the webpage script lives on the nodejs server, it does not actually run there - that's just where it is stored so that it can be sent to the browser when requested.  When it runs in the browser, it can only use browser APIs, not nodejs APIs.

The Javascript in your nodejs server itself runs on the server.  It can only use nodejs APIs, not browser APIs.  So, that's why nodejs Javascript cannot use `document.getElementsByName()`.  That only runs in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js does not run in a browser, thus there is no 'document' element in the first place. If you are asking how to parse an HTML file on the server side that's a different question.

Comment: Uh, nodejs does not run in a sandboxed environment.   It just runs on the server which is a completely different computer and environment from the browser.